# When the linear term of a variable is insignificant, is it reasonable to use an F-test to state that they are jointly statistically significant?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, f-test

I am running a multiple regression that takes the following simplified form (there are other variables not important to this question):
$$Y_{it}=\beta_0+\beta_{1}X_{it}+\beta_{2}X_{it}^2+u_{it}$$
$Y_{it}$ are crop yields in country $i$ at time $t$, and $X_{it}$ is temperature. The coefficient on the linear term is statistically insignificant both when I include and exclude the quadratic term. The quadratic term is statistically significant. When I run an F-test, the two are jointly significant (F=4.20, p=0.0152).

Is it reasonable to include the linear and quadratic pair and justify it by stating that the two are jointly significant as explanatory of $Y$? Can I still interpret the marginal effect of $X$ on $Y$ regularly?

I can't seem to find a close enough question to give me a reasonable answer.

Comment: Significant quadratic form is enough to say that X has effect on Y. Do not need joint significant.

Comment: But is it enough to say that the marginal effect is $\beta_{1}+2\beta_{2}X_{it}$? I'm concerned about the $\beta_{1}$. I am unsure about how to word the fact that the linear term is insignificant but the quadratic is significant therefore I include both?

Comment: I do not know what is marginal effect. You can think the regression line as quadratic curve symmetric with y-axis. In statistical modeling, if higher order term is significant, the lower order term should be kept in the model, just like simple linear regression, we always keep  the intercept in the model.

Comment: I don't think its the same as simple linear regression, I have an intercept in my model and thats not really related to my question about the explanatory variables. The marginal effect is essentially a first order partial derivative that gives a relationship that explains how $Y$ would change given a one unit change in $X$. For example, if $Y$ is crop yields and $X$ is temperature, using the above marginal effect, if I increase the temperature by 1$^o$C, crop yields would change on on by $\beta_{1}+2\beta_{2}X$ and in this example it varies with what temperature we are already at.

Comment: I will keep the lower order term, thank you!